# How do I reference a rectangle created programmatically, with XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working with WPF for the first time. I am creating a rectangle object & adding it as a child of a canvas.

How do I reference it in XAML?

I want to be able to rotate it over time but don't know how to access it from the MainWindow.xaml code...

I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere (maybe you can't do it this way?)

**Edit:**

I tried setting the `Name` property of the rectangle to `Test` (in C# code) and then doing

```
   <Rectangle x:Name="Test">
        <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-45"/>
        </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
    </Rectangle>
```

(This didn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a control in C#, you cannot access it in XAML. I think you must create the necessary animation in C# too.
Applying your rotation in C# could look like this:

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
rect.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = -45 };
parentPanel.Children.Add(rect);
```

The better way would be to generate the `Rectangle` in XAML and apply there the animation. But this depends on your exact situation. e.g. you can create a single `Rectangle` in XAML and use this one or you can bind an `ItemsControl` and create a `Rectangle` in the `ItemTemplate` for each entry in the binded list.